# htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given Laravel Error

Tags: laravel

i need help, i already have read another threads but i dont understand...

```
$serv  = DB::table('servicios')
      ->join('users_has_servicios', 'servicios.id', '=', 'users_has_servicios.servicios_id')
        ->select('servicios.name', 'servicios.id')
        ->where('users_id','=',auth()->user()->id)
        ->get();

     //$serv2=servicios::all(); 

$serv2 = DB::table('servicios')
      ->join('users_has_servicios', 'servicios.id', '=', 'users_has_servicios.servicios_id')          
       ->where('users_id','=',auth()->user()->id)
        ->get();

return view ('pagos.create',compact('serv'))->with('serv2',$serv2);
```

and my view:

```
<select  id="serv" name="serv" required onchange="ShowSelected()">
<option value="" selected disabled>seleccione servicio</option>


@foreach($serv as $id=>$name)

<option value="{{$id}}">{{$name}}</option>

@endforeach
```

when i use servicios::all() is not problem, but i need to filter the data i send... any idea?

thanks in advance

Comment: Try `@foreach($serv as $id = >$obj)
<option value="{{$id}}">{{$obj->name}}</option>`

Answer (score 0):

What you're iterating in the foreach is a collection of objects with properties, they're not indexed by id, you should iterate them like this:

```
<select  id="serv" name="serv" required onchange="ShowSelected()">
<option value="" selected disabled>seleccione servicio</option>


@foreach($serv as $servicio)

<option value="{{$servicio->id}}">{{$servicio->name}}</option>

@endforeach
```